# Looking for RH Kiddush audio file

Tags: rosh-hashanah-new-year, nuschaot, kiddush

Need answer fast!

I'm looking for an audio file of the Rosh Hashanah Kiddush, *in the RH melody*.  So far everything I've found uses the Hagim melody.  My usual go-to site, `virtualcantor.org`, doesn't have RH Kiddush at all.

Comment: In case it matters, I follow Ashkenazi minhag and nusach.

Comment: I've ben using virtual cantor the past week for studying Shacharit. I am unaware that there actually IS a special tune for Rosh Hashannah Kiddush, which may explain why you haven't found one. I've been to numerous shuls, and every chazzan (almost all of them "pros" - e.g. one trained in Vienna with some of the great chazzanim of early 20th century) and all used the standard Chagim tune with perhaps the ending of *Melech al kol ha'aretz* in the Rosh Hashannah tune. I'm curious if someone else can find something unique for RH. Of course, if you find for YK, I'd **really** be curious :-)

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LStrxKHkv9k

Comment: https://www.levisson.nl/images/stories/HF/RH%20arviet/13%20Kidoesj%20(Tucker)%20PG_1.mp3

Comment: https://www.shaarhashomayim.org/cd-volume-3-disc-1 track #4

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sZgG94Y6xmI

Comment: https://www.mediafire.com/file/bun232ukhevzn9c/7_Kiddush.mp3/file

Comment: https://www.kolhalashon.com/new/Media/PlayShiur.aspx?FileName=31078016&Lang=Hebrew

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N_90XFXz4hQ&t=236s

Comment: https://youtu.be/ePkNtUe-3Tk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an audio file of Rosh HaShanah kiddush, in a melody specific to Rosh HaShanah (which is based on the Yamim Nora'im Torah leynen melody):

<strike>http://www.ramaz.org/nusach/MP3s/RoshHashanah1/02_Kiddush.mp3</strike> *dead link 1 June 2022*

It is part of a collection of audio files demonstrating nusach, sung by Rabbi Haskel Lookstein. This is the index page:

[https://www.ramaz.org/page.cfm?p=5487](http://www.ramaz.org/nusach/index.html)

Comment: Thanks!  I've always wanted to make time to learn Y"N leyning nusach, so that file will help with this too.